# Bootstrap 3 grid - pull columns to the top as much as possible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `<row>` with 6 columns, height of each column is unknown. On small screen it should turn into 2 rows with 3 columns.

This is how it looks on md screen:
[image]

This is how it looks on sm screen:
[image]

I'm using the clearfix trick described in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

**Question:** how do I keep it in 2 rows of 3 columns but pull the columns to the top as much as possible? a4 should touch c1 and a5 should touch d2.

Full code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="color:black;font-size: 1.5em;">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">a0</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">b0</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">c0</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">d0</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">e0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">a1</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">b1</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">c1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">a2</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">b2</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">c2</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">d2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">a3</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">b3</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">c3</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">d3</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">e3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">a4</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">b4</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">c4</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">d4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">a5</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">b5</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">c5</div>
        <div style="background-color: white;">d5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd need JS for this—something like Isotope or Masonry. You can do it with CSS3, but older browsers won't support it:

Instead of floating the boxes, just add this to the container:

```
.row {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3; 
  column-count: 3; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ralph! I'll probably use masonry if I don't have a choice but was hoping someone can come up with a nice CSS trick that'll work with old browser.

Comment: So I gave mason a try and it's way easier than I expected and it's working! Thanks

Comment: Great. The only way to do it in older browsers without JS is to have wrappers around each column. But then you lose the responsiveness. Mind you, @media queries don't work in older browsers anyway.